# Issues connecting VMWare VM to Windows 7 (host)

Tags: windows-7, ssh, centos

I am on windows 7 trying to figure out why i cannot ping my computer or my VM from the other one, yet I am able to ping the router on both and other computers on the network. My desktop is running windows 7 64 bit and my vm is running CentOS 64 bit (which is what I use to test my web server stuff). At my school the VM has a dedicated IP and i don't have this issue, but I am home now and having issues trying to set this up behind my dumb router...I had already tried changing the VINC (i believe) to hide the vmnet1 and vmnet8 connections from the windows firewall and this seemed to have worked for like 5 minutes and then stopped...

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By default VMWare use network [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation). You can see yor configuration at `Virtual Machine Setting > Hardware > Network Adapter`. Change it to be Bridged, and it will simulate as "real" Network adapter.

Comment: Hi, i am using it as a bridged connection but I am experiencing all of these weird firewall/confliction errors between the host and the virtual machine.  Any other computer can connect to it on the network though.

Comment: I think you can try to disable iptables. try to follow http://www.lifelinux.com/how-to-enabledisable-firewall-on-centos-redhat-fedora/

Answer (score 0):

Check nameserver settings in /etc/resolv.conf.  Use Bridged networking.  In VMWare Edit configuration settings, look for automatically identify network setting.